# Updating UI for all Users Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, interface

So right now I have it so that when a User in my game creates an open game, an interface pops up with a join button and some information about the game which is great. I did this through RecylclerView and it works perfectly. However, this only updated the screen for the user who created the open game.

I am using the Realtime Database to store the open game information and that information is displayed through the updated interface. But how can I make it so that it updates the screen for every user that is on that specific page?

Which feature in Firebase will I be using to do something like this? I would just like a starting point and I can do research from there! I am assuming that Firebase Hosting is what I need to be using but I would just like some advice from you guys.

Thanks!

Comment: Use onDataChange() function for it. This link will help for u https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I've read through the description of onDataChange(). My current knowledge of this function is that it updates information once it is added or deleted. But will I also be able to use it to sort of make a 'live' lobby where when a game is added, every user in the lobby will see an interface that allows them to join this game?

Comment: You need to change any data within firebase when u want to trigger update for all players. It is simple way to do ur task

Comment: Can you give me an example of which data I would need to change in the database? I currently have it setup so whenever a user creates a game data is added to the database and displayed on the screen, but it is only displayed on the user who created the game's screen. Sorry if I am being difficult I am just trying to make sure I have explained my situation thoroughly enough :)

Comment: If u want to update data of all users all users must listen root of that updated data. It should not be exact root , but it should be parent node of that updated data. Simply add data structure which is listen by all users and then update it

Comment: Simply ur updated filed is only listen by specific person who creates server. You can expose that node to other users or create common node which is listen by all others then update that node

Comment: Got it this is helping a lot. Thank you man! I have attached my games to the onDataChange() function. But how do I make it so that multiple, or all, users can be exposed to a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Firebase RealtimeDatabase on our multiplayer mode as you want to do.

First, you need a player to create a game, that's something like

```
    roomDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Rooms").child(roomNumber)
```

and then set child's value.

And then you need everyone in the same gameroom to `listen` to the changes of the database reference.

You can choose on of these:

`roomDB.addChildEventListener(...)` to listen to it's child's change.

`roomDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)` to get it's value only one time.

`roomDB.addValueEventListener(...)` to listen to it's value until `.removeEventListener(...)`

I'm using `addValueEventListener` to sync data between players. It has about 0.5~1 sec delay. And remember to `removeEventListener` when the game is over.

In the end, FYI,
You might want to see `Transaction` class of Firebase. That can promise you players won't write data to the same place at the same time. For example: make sure there won't be 5 players in a 4 players game.

--- Update --

```
final DatabaseReference playersDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Rooms") // end here if you want to listen to all rooms
            .child(roomId)  // end here if you want to listen to THIS room
            .child("Players"); // I end here because I only want players' data
playersDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot ds) {
         // update UI here;
         }
 }
```

Comment: Awesome, this really helped thank you a lot. Using the addChildEventListener(), it now works so that the users are both reading from the same node so if one user creates a game, their game is added to the lobby screen, and if a second player creates a game then there are 2 games added to the lobby screen. But I still don't have it updating in real time. How can I update the screen every, oh say 1 second or so that way it can update the UI in real time? Should addChildEventListener() be doing this already?

Comment: I've made an update of my post, you should create the scripts inside `onDataChage`. By doing so, if the data changed, the UI can be updated in a short delay.  There are many method in `childEventListener`, maybe you can try `addValueEventListener` to only listen to the `onDataChange()`.

Comment: Alright thank you man. I don't quite having it working perfectly for me yet but I am going to play around with it and see how I can tweak things. Thanks for all your help!